# How to auto-reconnect to XMPP server?

Tags: java, spring, xmpp, smack

I have an application which is supposed to keep permanent connection to a XMPP server. But every 2 or 3 days, it disconnects, and can't reconnect automatically with ReconnectionManager as it is supposed to do.

What could I do to see what is happening and/or to correct this ?

```
2018-09-20 07:06:10.887 -  WARN - o.j.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection         : Connection closed with error
java.net.SocketException: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente (Read failed)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:212)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:2992)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1144)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1177)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:956)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:971)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my Connection conf (Spring java-style config) :

```
  @Bean("xmppConnection")
  public XmppConnectionFactoryBean xmppConnectionFactoryBean() {

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(appProperties.getXmpp().getUsername(), appProperties.getXmpp().getPassword());
    configBuilder.setServiceName(appProperties.getXmpp().getServiceName());
    configBuilder.setHost(appProperties.getXmpp().getHost());
    int port = appProperties.getXmpp().getPort();
    if (port != 0) {
      configBuilder.setPort(port);
    }
    int timeout = appProperties.getXmpp().getTimeout();
    if (timeout != 0) {
      configBuilder.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    }
    configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(appProperties.getXmpp().isDebuggerEnabled());
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = configBuilder.build();

    XmppConnectionFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean = new XmppConnectionFactoryBean();
    connectionFactoryBean.setConnectionConfiguration(config);
    connectionFactoryBean.setSubscriptionMode(null);

    return connectionFactoryBean;
  }
```

And here is where the connection is used in Spring Integration conf :

```
<int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter id="xmppInboundAdapter" channel="xmppInbound" xmpp-connection="xmppConnection" auto-startup="true" />
```

UPDATE : To audit the issue, I've just added a listener to xmppConnection :

```
  @Bean("xmppConnection")
  public XMPPConnection xmppConnection(XmppConnectionFactoryBean xmppConnectionFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    XMPPConnection xmppConnection = xmppConnectionFactoryBean.getObject();
    xmppConnection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

      @Override
      public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        logger.info("Successfully reconnected to the XMPP server.");
      }

      @Override
      public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
        logger.info("Failed to reconnect to the XMPP server.");
      }

      @Override
      public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
        logger.info("Reconnecting in " + seconds + " seconds.");
      }

      @Override
      public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
        logger.error("Connection to XMPP server was lost.");
      }

      @Override
      public void connectionClosed() {
        logger.info("XMPP connection was closed.");
      }

      @Override
      public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {
        logger.info("Connected to XMPP server.");        
      }

      @Override
      public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
        logger.info("Authenticated to XMPP server.");        
      }
    });

    return xmppConnection;

  }
```

UPDATE 2 :
now with the audit activated, I can see :

```
2018-10-03 07:29:39.442 - ERROR - f.e.r.l.i.xmpp.config.XmppManagerConfig  : Connection to XMPP server was lost.
```

but never "Reconnecting in" or "Failed to reconnect".

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope you are using latest version of smack 4.3.0

> By default Smack will try to reconnect the connection in case it was
>   abruptly disconnected. The reconnection manager will try to
>   immediately reconnect to the server and increase the delay between
>   attempts as successive reconnections keep failing.
>
> In case you want to force a reconnection while the reconnection manager is waiting for the
>   next reconnection, you can just use `AbstractXMPPConnection#connect()`
>   and a new attempt will be made. If the manual attempt also failed then
>   the reconnection manager will still continue the reconnection job.

Comment: Yeah, well, as you can see, it does not reconnect "by default". I'll make an answer with the necessary code.